# Is it possible to create root domains with MAMP?

Tags: dns, localhost, mamp

Currently, my workflow is to develop locally, and then place on remote server as key intervals. This has worked fine for a while, but since starting to do more AJAX work, I am finding it difficult to work with roots and hosts dynamically, and am having to write redundant code into my JS in order to make the same file work both locally and remotely.

Is there a good way to mimic a URL locally, or even just have  each local site have a root level domain address (as apposed to localhost/my-dev-site) using MAMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a host file , point it to localhost

You mentioned MAMP, so I am assuming you are using Mac.

go to /etc/hosts  and add this line:

```
127.0.0.1   www.whateveryoururl.com
```

OR

```
127.0.0.1   www.whateveryoururl.com whateveryoururl.com
```

Comment: okay, assuming that I did this, how can I then see the live version?

Comment: uncomment the line in /etc/hosts